# React Native: renderRow not executed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In the following code, when `setState` is called from `campaignsUpdated`, `render` gets logged to the console, but not `renderRow`:

```
var React = require('react-native'),

Bus = require('../Bus'),
styles = require('../Styles'),
CampaignsStore = require('../stores/Campaigns'),
CampaignItem = require('./CampaignItem'),

{
  Component,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  ListView,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
  ActivityIndicatorIOS
} = React


class CampaignList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2})
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      this.addListeners()
      Bus.emit('campaigns:search', '')
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this.removeListeners()
    }

    render() {
      console.log('render')
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.searchInput}
            placeholder='Campaign Name'
            value={this.state.campaignName}
            onChange={this.campaignSearchChanged.bind(this)}/>
          <ListView
            dataSource = {this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow = {this.renderRow.bind(this)}/>
        </View>
      )
    }

    renderRow(campaign) {
      console.log('renderRow')
      return <CampaignItem campaign={campaign}/>
    }

    addListeners() {
      Bus.on({
        'campaigns:updated': this.campaignsUpdated.bind(this)
      })
    }

    removeListeners() {
      Bus.off({
        'campaigns:updated': this.campaignsUpdated.bind(this)
      })
    }

    campaignsUpdated(event) {
      var campaigns = event.data
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(campaigns)
      })
    }

    campaignSearchChanged(event) {
      var campaignName = event.nativeEvent.text
      Bus.emit('campaigns:search', campaignName)
    }
}

module.exports = CampaignList
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `ListView` a function `renderRow` that returns a component. You would have to call that function within `ListView` once it is passed, presumably during a map over `campaigns`.

Comment: Also it seems that you are calling `this.renderRow.bind(this)` but I don't see a reason for passing context to `renderRow`.

Comment: why do I have to call renderRow? It renders correctly the first time, so I'm assuming ListView maps over the campaigns as you mentioned, without the component having to do so.

Comment: Oops missed that this was react native sorry. Must be not hitting the `rowHasChanged` function because either your data isn't changing or the `cloneWithRows` doesn't trigger a rowChange?

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it the most likely case is that you have a classic React mutability issue here.

I.e. I suspect your 'campaignsUpdated' method is called with either the same Array instance it received last time, or the elements within the list are the same instances.

Try using:

```
campaignsUpdated(event) {
  var campaigns = event.data.slice(); // <-- clone the array
  this.setState({
    dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(campaigns)
  })
}
```

If that doesn't work, then you either make the part that manages your list of compaigns create new copies when changes are made (e.g. `const clone = {...campaign, title:"A new Title"}`) or update your rowHasChanged method to see if the title (or whatever data you need) has actually changed.

Here are two really good videos about immutability in JavaScript here: 
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-array-mutations-with-concat-slice-and-spread
https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-object-mutations-with-object-assign-and-spread